# Toast is not showing in a google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, toast

here is the xml file of that button

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:onClick="onSearch"/>
```

here is the java code

```
 public void onSearch(View view) {

        to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
        String locate = to.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (locate != null || !locate.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locate, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Please enter a valid location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

when the textField is empty and the button is clicked it should show a toast but after clicking the button it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to find your textview outside of your method suggested in onCreate()

```
        to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
public void onSearch(View view) {

        String locate = to.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (locate != null || !locate.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locate, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Please enter a valid location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add method body,
Make 'findViewById' abstract

Comment: have to added that line in onCreate() Method ?

Comment: i tried by finding the EditText in oncreate() but app stops after clicking the button

Comment: This will be usefull          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Please enter a valid location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();